Can ExperimentalLettuceCoroutinesApi for connecting to REDIS be used in production?
hi I am working on a production application to connect to AWS Elasticache REDIS using Kotlin. The TPS in production will be 1M.
I am using Lettuce client and my code is written in kotlin. I came across this kotlin api reference in https://lettuce.io/core/6.1.4.RELEASE/reference/#kotlin and saw the async command to connect to REDIS is marked with experimental annotation.
"Coroutine Extensions are experimental and require opt-in using @ExperimentalLettuceCoroutinesApi. The API ships with a reduced feature set. Deprecated methods and StreamingChannel are left out intentionally. Expect evolution towards a Flow-based API to consume large Redis responses."
Has anyone used this in production ? can we use it ?

FWIW the team is considering to remove the annotation soon, see https://github.com/redis/lettuce/issues/2527
